# How to create a matrix from a given text file?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a simple maze game, where the matrix should be some kind of a map of the maze. I'm given a text file without spaces and I want to create a matrix from it.

This is what I have already tried:

```
txt = open('matrix.txt')
matrix = []
for line in txt:
    for character in line:
        matrix.append(character.split())
```

For example, my text file looks like this:

```
xxxxx
xS--x
xx-Fx
xxxxx
```

So, if I write `matrix[1][1]`, I want my program to return `S`, however it does not, because I probably did not create a matrix.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the  following method:

```
    txt = open('matrix.txt')
    matrix = []
    for line in txt:
        matrix.append([])
        for character in line:
            if (character != "\n"):
                matrix[-1].append(character)
```

I'm not sure that this is the best way to do it, but never the less, it works.

Comment: I think I understand whole your code but I probably would not have the idea to use matrix[-1]. What exactly does this do?

Comment: In this code, matrix is actually a array of arrays. And matrix[-1] means the last member of matrix. This is also equal to matrix[len(matrix) - 1].

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to achieve your goal:

```
txt = open('matrix.txt')
matrix = []
for line in txt:
    line_list = [l for l in list(line) if l != '\n']
    matrix.append(line_list)

print(matrix)
print(matrix[1][1])
```

> **Output**

```
[['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'], ['x', 'S', '-', '-', 'x'], ['x', 'x', '-', 'F', 'x'], ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x']]
S
```

> **UPDATE:** list-comprehension is straight forwad. But there is another way to achieve your goal.

```
for line in txt:
line_list = []
for l in list(line):
    if l != '\n':
        line_list.append(l)
    matrix.append(line_list)

print(matrix)
print(matrix[1][1])
```

> **Output**

```
[['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'], ['x', 'S', '-', '-', 'x'], ['x', 'x', '-', 'F', 'x'], ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x']]
S
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what 'l for l' means and does in the program. Could you please explain?

Comment: `[l for l in list(line) if l != '\n']` It is a synthax to create a `list comprehension`. It generates a list like this `['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x']`.